# Windows 10 program to assign jobs to employees, in construction business

Tags: gui, data-visualization

I have been asked to develop a small application by a friend of mine. He runs a small construction business. At the moment, he keeps track of what jobs his employees are assigned to using a table drawn on a whiteboard. Each "cell" has a job name associated with it, and colour coded magnets are stuck to the whiteboard in each job cell to indicate which employee is assigned where.

He basically wants me to create a desktop application that accomplishes this exact task, including the ability to create a new job and add small graphical indicators corresponding to an employee. He wants to be able to drag/drop these "magnets" between jobs, since employees are often reassigned. The idea is to put this display on a big screen in the office, so everyone can see who is where.

Does an application that can accomplish this task already exist? I'm not opposed to doing this for him, but if something is already out there that can do this, I'd rather not write a potentially buggy app when a better version could already be out there and ready to go.

This should run on Windows 10. Price range would ideally be free, or fairly inexpensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few software packages that provide this type of functionality.

One free and straight forward and easy to setup and use is [Trello](https://trello.com/)

You can drag and drop group members from task to task as needed it also allows you to create tasks that have deadlines that warn when they are close to their end time.

Well worth a go.

If you want more of a timetable graph type of functionality then you should look at [Gantt Chart Software](https://www.workzone.com/blog/gantt-chart-software/)

It is quite common for construction projects as you can see an overall timeline and each task as a bar with its own start and end times including benchmarks.

Each task can also include number of people/contractors and work out a budget and cost projections.

Gannt Charts do not usually have any drag and drop functionality and it can seem a bit intimidating when it comes to setting up and has a bit of a steep learning curve but it can be really useful to view the whole project in one go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll leave it open for a little while longer, but I'll accept your answer if nothing else comes in.

Comment: Not a problem; let us know what worked for you, even if it wasn't one of my potential solutions, as it can help others that have a similar query.